# CITY/AREA dynamic field fetching from the custom API Woocommerce

Tags: jquery, ajax, woocommerce

I am developing a plugin for shipping and I want to implement city/area dynamically. I have added the custom field and I want to populate the area field whenever the city is selected or changed. The area dropdown is fetched from a custom API using another action

Here is the form
[image]

/function to get Areas

```
function cities_areas_settings() {
    $text_domain = 'woocommerce';

    global $woocommerce;
   
    if (isset($_POST['liveCity'])) { 
        
        $towns = [1122 =>ABA, 1123 => IBADAN, 1124>oyo ];
    }
           
    return array($towns);
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'custom_checkout_js_script');
function custom_checkout_js_script() {
    if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :
    // Initializing
    $text_domain   = 'woocommerce';
    $karachi_areas = array( '' => __('Choose your area', $text_domain) );

    $areas = cities_areas_settings(); // Load settings

    

    ?><script language="javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        var a = 'select[name="billing_city"]',
            b = 'select[name="billing_area"]',
            o = <?php echo json_encode($areas); ?>,
            s = $(b).html();

        // Utility function to fill dynamically the select field options
        function dynamicSelectOptions(opt) {

            var options = '';

            for (var i = 0; i < opt.length; i++) {

                console.log(opt.length)
                options += '<option value="' + opt[i] + '">' + opt[i] + '</option>';

            }
            $(o).html(options);

            // $.each( opt, function(key, value ){
            //     options += '<option value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>';
            // });

        }

        // On Start (once DOM is loaded)
        if ($(a).val() != '') {
            console.log("testa");
            dynamicSelectOptions(o);
        }

        console.log($(a).val());

        // On billing city change live event
        $('form.woocommerce-checkout').on('change', a, function() {
            var test = $(this).val();;
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                var data = {
                    'action': 'my_action',
                    'liveCity': test
                };

                jQuery.post(window.location, data, function(response) {
                    //  console.log('Got this from the server: ' + response);
                });
            });


            var testing = dynamicSelectOptions(o);
            console.log(testing);

        });
    });
</script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Here is the jQuery code I am using. When the city is changed, the response shows the page is populated but like this

[image]

Comment: Actually your code is not testable *(the function `cities_areas_settings()` is not defined)* and we don't know with the provided information what is the problem. Note that *"The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem**"*. see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The function has been added. Thanks

Comment: Sorry but `ClicknShip_Shipping_Method()` and `ClicknShipAPI()` Classes are not defined either. see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please see the edited version. Thanks